# How to move a PictureBox created at runtime?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I’m working on an application in VB.NET where I create a copy of a PictureBox and add it to a Panel at runtime. **I want to be able to move this copy of the PictureBox with the mouse after it has been dropped on the Panel**. I’ve tried handling the **MouseDown, MouseMove, and MouseUp events of the PictureBox copy, but it doesn’t seem to work.** Here’s the code I’m using (when i drag the picturebox1 and create the new one):

```
`Public Sub NewPictureBoxWhenIsDraggedOriginal()
pictureBoxCopy = New PictureBox()
pictureBoxCopy.Image = PictureBox1.Image
pictureBoxCopy.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
pictureBoxCopy.Size = PictureBox1.Size
pictureBoxCopy.Location = PictureBox1.Location
Panel2.Controls.Add(pictureBoxCopy)
AddHandler pictureBoxCopy.MouseDown, AddressOf Me.PictureBoxCopy_MouseDown
AddHandler pictureBoxCopy.MouseMove, AddressOf Me.PictureBoxCopy_MouseMove
AddHandler pictureBoxCopy.MouseUp, AddressOf Me.PictureBoxCopy_MouseUp
Private Sub PictureBoxCopy_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
' Set isDragging to True to indicate that the PictureBox is being dragged
isDragging = True


dragOffset = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBoxCopy_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
' Check if the PictureBox is being dragged
If isDragging Then
    ' Update the PictureBox location to follow the mouse cursor
    Dim newLocation As Point = pictureBoxCopy.Location
    newLocation.X += e.X - dragOffset.X
    newLocation.Y += e.Y - dragOffset.Y
    pictureBoxCopy.Location = newLocation
End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBoxCopy_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
' Set isDragging to False to indicate that the PictureBox has been dropped
isDragging = False
End Sub`
```

Can anyone help me understand why I can’t move the PictureBox copy and how I could fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Guys i tried with add handlers on the runtime, but it doesn't work, well, first there is an original picturebox, (PictureBox1) that when i try to drag it a copy is that i can drag (and drop) on the panel (Panel2), but when i drop, i can't move the copy anymore, i tried adding handlers, but i doesn't work because, (i think that handlers run on the sub, and thats because dont work), then i dont know how to make the object (that is not declarated) can move, on the panel area, because i cant say on code that when the mouse move an object that is not declared on the VS Designer...

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly. Provide everything we need and nothing we don't. If you need to create a new project with just the relevant functionality, do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting your PictureBoxCopy location to the same as the source, it's on top of the original Picturebox. You're putting it into a panel anyway, don't set the location. Here's my code that works.

```
Dim isDragging As Boolean
Dim dragOffset As Point

Dim pictureBoxCopy As New PictureBox()

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    NewPictureBoxWhenIsDraggedOriginal()
End Sub

Public Sub NewPictureBoxWhenIsDraggedOriginal()

    pictureBoxCopy.Image = PictureBox1.Image
    pictureBoxCopy.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    pictureBoxCopy.Size = PictureBox1.Size

    'pictureBoxCopy.Location = PictureBox1.Location

    Panel2.Controls.Add(pictureBoxCopy)

    AddHandler pictureBoxCopy.MouseDown, AddressOf Me.pictureBoxCopy_MouseDown
    AddHandler pictureBoxCopy.MouseMove, AddressOf Me.pictureBoxCopy_MouseMove
    AddHandler pictureBoxCopy.MouseUp, AddressOf Me.pictureBoxCopy_MouseUp

End Sub

Private Sub pictureBoxCopy_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    ' Set isDragging to True to indicate that the PictureBox is being dragged
    isDragging = True


    dragOffset = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
End Sub


Private Sub pictureBoxCopy_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    ' Check if the PictureBox is being dragged
    If isDragging Then
        ' Update the PictureBox location to follow the mouse cursor
        Dim newLocation As Point = pictureBoxCopy.Location
        newLocation.X += e.X - dragOffset.X
        newLocation.Y += e.Y - dragOffset.Y
        pictureBoxCopy.Location = newLocation
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub pictureBoxCopy_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    ' Set isDragging to False to indicate that the PictureBox has been dropped
    isDragging = False
End Sub
```